# VueJS Datepicker: dynamically change data based on month

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, datepicker, vue-component

I am new to VueJS and I'm incorporating the [`vue-hotel-datepicker`](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker) library into my project.

**Goal**: change the `minNights` data property depending on the month. I was able to simply override that value as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker#minnights).

[image]

**Problem**: `minNights` should be 8 in August and July. When I use the Vue inspector, I can see that the `HotelDatePicker` component (imported from the library) has an 'activeMonthIndex', so I believe I should use that. But how can I access this data property from my parent? How can I dynamically change the `minNights` property based on the month?

[image]

My template:

```
<datepicker
    :startDate="startDate"
    @check-in-changed="setCheckInDate"
    @check-out-changed="setCheckOutDate"
    :maxNights="21"
    :minNights="minNights" //dynamic based on month
    :checkIn="checkIn"
    :checkOut="checkOut"
    :disabledDates="bookedDates"
    :firstDayOfWeek="1"
    :i18n="lang"
    :showYear="true"
 >
```

I have made a [`gist`](https://gist.github.com/heleneshaikh/1fa634436826e4225433066e60049544) for those who wish to see my code.
Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: please what's your specific question?

Comment: I wish to change the minNights property based on the month. I edited my question to be clearer. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `minNights` prop should be bound to a `computed` property like :

```
<datepicker
:startDate="startDate"
@check-in-changed="setCheckInDate"
@check-out-changed="setCheckOutDate"
:maxNights="21"
:minNights="minNights" //dynamic based on month
:checkIn="checkIn"
:checkOut="checkOut"
:disabledDates="bookedDates"
:firstDayOfWeek="1"
:i18n="lang"
:showYear="true"
>
```

script :

```
  computed:{
        minNights(){

          let currentMonth=this.$children[0]._data.activeMonthIndex;
          if(currentMonth==6 || currentMonth==7){
             return currentMonth;
           }   
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I set minNights to a specific month? The only visible property I can work with, I think, is the one from my second screenshot (the activeMonthIndex which is generated by the HotelDatepicker library). How can I access it / is there a better way? I need to link a month to my minNights.

Comment: when i check the [`code`](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker/blob/master/src/components/DatePicker.vue) the value of activeMonthIndex is not emitted from that component

Comment: Then I wonder where that property comes from. I only see it when I click on the HotelDatePicker component within the Vue dev tools. Any idea how I can access the month in another way then? Thank you.

Comment: in this way you couldn't, did you try to get the month from `newCheckIn`?

Comment: @Brahim, the problem is that I need to set the `minNights` and need access to a month, before the `newCheckin` is initialized...

Comment: I know, but the problem is that I need to set the `minNights` BEFORE the `newCheckin` gets initialized... So I need to set that `minNights` property before the user starts interacting with my datepicker. Thank you for your help, I hope we'll find a solution.

Comment: please explain me the role of `activeMonthIndex` maybe i suggest you an alternative solution

Comment: the `activeMonthIndex` gives me 0 when the datepicker shows the January view. It gives me 1 when February comes into view, etc. 
You can see how it is set in the library https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker/blob/master/src/components/Day.vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186068/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-helenesh).